# Graphing Functions and its Inverse

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graphing-functions

I have received this question for my homework, and I am quite unsure on how I should attempt to answer this. Can someone please explain how I can go about solving this?

Let $\:f : \Bbb R →]1, +∞[$ with $f(x) = 2^x + 1$.

(a) Find the inverse function

(b) Plot the curves of both functions, $f$ and $f^{-1}$ in the same graph.

(c) What can you say about these two curves?

[my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIajE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y=f^{-1}(x)$, we get $x=f(y)$ . Find the inverse by interchanging $x$ and $y$ and solving for $y$.

To wit, we get $x=2^y+1$, and we solve for $y$.  Get $2^y=x-1$.  Now use $\ln$, say.  Get $y=\dfrac {\ln(x-1)}{\ln2}$.

After plotting the two curves, you will notice that they are reflections of each other about the line $y=x$.  (That's the effect of interchanging $x$ and $y$.)

Comment: So how exactly will my graph look? Will the curve of the inverse start from y=0? Or will it be a full curve?

Comment: The domain of the inverse is $]1,\infty [$.

Comment: Is there any way I can share an image with you, so as to look a my graph?

Comment: Probably,  but, you should eventually know what the graphs of $y=e^x$ and $y=\ln x$ look like.  And they're reflections of each other about $y=x$ (as mentioned).

Comment: I have added an image of my graph to the question.

Comment: I guess you could snap a picture.   Or Google to get a look at them.

Comment: Yes.  Looks good.

Comment: So i dont need to remove any part of the curve?
The codomain of the function is ]1, +infiniti[. So wont I have to start my curve from the exact one or something?

Comment: Yes, as i said.

Comment: So the graph I attached, is it correct?

Comment: It looks right.

Comment: Okay great. Thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: Sure Lester.  Anytime.